# Quotes of irony, are they used often?

Tags: grammar, quotations

I am under impression that native English writers rarely (compared to e.g. Russian) use quotes to express irony, but often explicitly write "so called ...".

What about usage of quotes of irony in English? Is it in fact rarer than in Russian?

Comment: Obviously "scare quotes" (do they have a special name in Russian?) are only really relevant to ***written*** language. I can't imagine a BBC newsreader doing [air quotes](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/air-quotes) with their fingers while telling us about the latest "Islamic State" atrocity. Bear in mind that both usages (orthographic and gestural) apply to more than just *ironic* contexts. Personally, I would also contend that it's the *British*, not the Russians, who are "Masters of Irony / Understatement" (so much so that we don't always need to "advertise" it! :)

Comment: This might be better-answered at [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/), where someone might know of a study on the use of sneer markers (scare quotes, but also phrases like *popularly known as*, *sometimes called*, *would-be*, *self-proclaimed*,  *said to be*, and so on) in English as opposed to other languages. Also relevant there is *[When is it appropriate to use “scare quotes”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69547)*